# Jquery Selectors not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I use the following selector to get the value out of an input that's inside a table
but it doesnt work properly?

```
var kom =$("tr#1 .b input").attr(value);
```

and row looks as follow

```
  <tr class="numbers" id="1">
   <td class="a" align="right">1</td>
   <td class="a" align="left">Tue</td>
   <td class="b"><input class="input" type="text" title="" value=""/></td>
   <td class="c"><input class="input" type="text" title="" value=""/></td>
   <td class="d"><input class="input" type="text" title="" value=""/></td>
   <td class="e"><input class="input" type="text" title="" value=""/></td>
   <td class="f">0</td>
   <td class="g"><input class="input" type="text" title="" value=""/></td>
 </tr>
```

any suggestion on what i might be doing wrong
any aid is greatly appreciated

regards
breezer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two problems here, first your IDs should *not* start with a number, use a prefix, like `row1`, then use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value, like this:

```
var kom =$("tr#row1 .b input").val();
```

*If* you were to use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), you would use it like this `.attr('value')`, currently it's looking for `.attr(undefined)`.  I put if in italics because you should pretty much always use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get or set a value on an `<input>`...same goes for `<select>` and `<textarea>`.

Comment: I assume "your IDs should start with a number" should read "your IDs should **not** start with a number" ?

Comment: @edl - Agreed, I prefer to change as little as possible from the question to demonstrate only the egregious problems though :)  Good note none the less, unless there's the possibility of this same ID on another element type that shouldn't match, it's extraneous.

Comment: the actual problem was the quotes but I appreciate the recommendations for the other things so ill mark this as the accurate answer

Answer (score 5):

Try putting *value* in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing the DOM's value attribute can be a bit funky. Try this:

```
var kom =$("tr#1 .b input").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("tr#1 .b input").attr("value");`

Watch that you haven't enclosed value in "value".

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

var kom = $(".b input").val();

Answer (score 0):

```
var kom =$("tr#1 .b input").attr("value")
```

or better

```
var kom =$("tr#1 .b input").val();
```